# Como dividir uma string com duas condições

Tags: haskell

Basicamente, da string `"222 2333 33"`, eu queria dividir em várias strings, quando encontra um espaço vazio ou um número diferente ao seu lado.

Por exemplo, na string de cima queria que ficasse `["222","2","333","33"]`.

O código que fiz encontra-se abaixo, só que no meu caso apenas consigo dividir quando encontra o espaço vazio. Faltando quando os números são diferentes.

```
sliceIt :: String -> [String]

sliceIt xs = words xs
```

E seria possível fazer este problema com recursão?

Comment: Não pode usar uma função já pronta? [split](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4978742/4551469)

Comment: Posso, mas neste caso como usaria? Pois eu quero que ele faça split sempre que encontra espaço vazio ou um numero diferente

Comment: Fiz o que pude para melhorar a edição, mas por favor: NÃO USE IMAGEM, coloque o código

Comment: não vou saber responder porque não manjo nada de haskell, mas uma sugestão é você percorrer a _string_, quando encontrar um cara diferente do anterior, adicionar um espaço em branco (`" "`) e depois usar o _split_..

Answer (score 0):

Se quiser definir a sua própria versão, fica aqui uma alternativa recursiva usando a função [`span`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=span)

```
sliceIt :: String -> [String]
sliceIt [] = []
sliceIt (' ':xs) = sliceIt xs
sliceIt (x:xs) = let (a, b) = span (==x) (x:xs) 
               in a:(sliceIt b)
```

span é uma função que recebe um predicado `p` e uma lista `l` e que devolve um tuplo de `l` com os elementos que satisfazem o predicado `p` e onde o segundo elemento do tuplo são os restantes elementos de `l`. `span p l` é equivalente a `(takeWhile p l, dropWhile p l)` pela que a versão anterior pode ser considerada equivalente a:

```
sliceIt :: String -> [String]
sliceIt [] = []
sliceIt (' ':xs) = sliceIt xs
sliceIt (x:xs) = (x : (takeWhile (== x) xs)) : (sliceIt $ dropWhile (== x) xs)
```

Fica aqui ainda uma outra alternativa usando apenas funções pré-definidas nos modulos Prelude e List

```
import Data.List

sliceIt :: String -> [String]
sliceIt = concatMap group . words
```